# Javascript variable to php variable conversion method working. But I could not compare that php variable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

To send javascript variable to php variable we have to use POST or Ajax.

Below code converts javascript variable to php variable without using POST, Get or Ajax methods 
When I echo php variable it gives the proper value, so I assumed the javascript value is assigned to php variable.

But as php scripts process from the server side, Why js variable is assigned to php variable on onClick function?

Let it to be. Js variable is assigned to php variable now. and it is displaying proper value.
But why comparison of php variable is not working?

Demo: http://ibence.com/jstophp.php

```
<script>
function jstophp(){

var javavar=document.getElementById("text").value;  
document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML="<?php 

$phpvar='"+javavar+"'; 
echo 'Converted from js variable to php variable:'.$phpvar;


if($phpvar=='a'){
    echo '<br>You have typed letter a';
}

else{
    echo '<br>If you have not typed letter a, this program is working according to logic. but if you have entered letter a, why this message is displaying?';
}

?>";
}

</script> 
<body>

<div id="rslt"></div>

<input type="text" id="text" />
<button onClick="jstophp()" >Convert js to php</button>

</body>
```

Comment: javascript and php are decoupled, and there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. It does not assign a PHP variable to a string read from textfield. It just assigns it a literal value of `"+javavar+"` which is then displayed into your JavaScript code. So you're actually displaying a JavaScript variable called `javavar`.

See how your script looks like after PHP processing:

```
<script>
function jstophp(){

var javavar=document.getElementById("text").value;  
document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML="Converted from js variable to php variable:"+javavar+"<br>If you have not typed letter a, this program is working according to logic. but if you have entered letter a, why this message is displaying?";
}

</script>
```

Can you see how the string `"+javavar+"` got embedded there to create a working JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending any data to the server, and in your code:

```
<?php
$phpvar='"+javavar+"';  // assigning "+javavar+" to $phpvar which stays like that
if($phpvar=='a'){ // which is not true since $phpvar= "+javavar+" !
    echo '<br>You have typed letter a';
}else{
 // your message ...
}

?>
```